# nextval and curval confusion in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, scope-identity, nextval

What will happen if multiple user run the following query at the same time?

```
INSERT INTO "Retail"."Attributes"("AttributeId","AttributeCode","AttributeName")
VALUES(nextval('"Retail"."CompoundUnits_CompoundUnitId_seq"'::regclass),'COL','Color');

INSERT INTO "Retail"."AttributeDetails"  
  ("AttributeId","AttributeDetailCode","AttributeDetailName")
VALUES
(
  currval('"Retail"."CompoundUnits_CompoundUnitId_seq"'::regclass), 'COL-Red', 'Color Red'
),
(
  currval('"Retail"."CompoundUnits_CompoundUnitId_seq"'::regclass), 'COL-Blu', 'Color Blue'
), 
(
  currval('"Retail"."CompoundUnits_CompoundUnitId_seq"'::regclass), 'COL-Gre', 'Color Green'
);
```

Is this as method as reliable as SCOPE_IDENTITY() of SQL SERVER? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sequences will be as, if not more, reliable than SCOPE_IDENTITY(): http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value

Answer (score 4):

`currval()` is session specific. If a separate session increments your sequence, currval() will continue to return your expected value.

That said you may want to use `insert returning`:

```
insert into foo values (...) returning id;

insert into bar (foo_id, ...) values (:id, ...),  (:id, ...), ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation - 'multiple sessions are guaranteed to allocate distinct sequence values'

So you will get distinct values but depending on the 'cache' setting specified while creating the sequence object, the values obtained across various concurrent sessions might not always be sequential.
Read the documentation on [sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html), especially the 'cache' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of currval is perfectly OK

I don't know SCOPE_IDENTITY() so I cannot compare the two concepts.

Btw: you don't need the cast in your statement:

`currval('"Retail"."CompoundUnits_CompoundUnitId_seq"')`

is enough

Comment: Not ture, you don't have to have autocommit turned off.  currval is perfectly safe outside a transaction

Comment: +1 Scott. currval() is initialized for a session, and is concurrency safe. It's the reason you cannot call it prior to using nextval(), or setval() with the boolean flag set accordingly.

Comment: Sequences really mess with people's heads.  They're transaction safe because they are independent of all transactional semantics, kinda living outside of them.  Took me a while to wrap my head around them when I got started.